# Career cars in race day mode in NFS Pro Street?

Tags: need-for-speed-prostreet

I have got some cool cars in career mode of NFS Pro Street. But I want to race them in race day mode. How can I do it? When I choose a custom race day, I see some boring cars and my career cars aren't there. Any way to do this ?

Comment: What version of Pro Street are you referring to (PC, PS3/360, DS/PSP, Wii)?

Comment: The PC version it is

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the PC version, but on my wii you can use your own cars on certain maps. Also on the wii version, you have to press a button to change a tier which allows you to access your own cars.

Comment: If the wii has this functionality, google to verify the same, then add your source as well as the steps with using the default keystrokes.